# SSIS package after execution

Tags: ssis

New to MS BI, I am getting an error after execution completed.

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\FirstSSIS\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [20]: The processing of file "C:\Users\Sangeet\Desktop\Test1.txt" has started.
Error: 0xC0202071 at Data Flow Task, SQL Server Destination [41]: Unable to bulk copy data. You may need to run this package as an administrator.
Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SQL Server Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202071.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [20]: The processing of file "C:\Users\Sangeet\Desktop\Test1.txt" has ended.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "SQL Server Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "C:\Users\Sangeet\source\repos\FirstSSIS\FirstSSIS\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[24072] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `Unable to bulk copy data. You may need to run this package as an administrator.` Are you running this package as an administrator?

Comment: how to run this package as admin

Comment: perfect mate.it has done

Answer (score 0):

run package as an administrator

Comment: Oh, you are the OP. This was in low quality posts.